# When I should create new tag, using semantic versioning and the git flow?

Tags: tags, git-flow

Should I create tag any time I merge to master, and any time I merge in develop.

Inside master when version is like x.y.z, and inside develop when version could be x.y-feature-merged and/or x.y-(RC1|BETA|ALFA).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would create a tag each time to do a release (merge to master) and git-flow should take care of that automatically.

If you use git-flow AVH the tag will be merged back in to develop.

I sometimes do a tag in develop if it's a big feature I merged, tag would be x.y.z-dev.w where w is the amount of commits since the last release.
Otherwise I hardly use tags. I'm sure other people would use tags more often than myself.

So this would be my tag layout:
Production: x.y.z
Develop: x.y.z-dev.w
Release Branch: x.y.z-rc.a => a being a regular counter

Comment: Now I just think these are guidelines: anybody should find its own way to work with git.